# How to do a multi-level CLI in Python?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, tab-completion

I'm trying to do a CLI, preferrably written in Python. I need a multi-level CLI, and I want tab completion.

I looked at the cmd module (from the Python standard library) and readline with the "complete" function (for tab completion).

They both lacked at something, i.e. I haven't figured out how to handle multiple levels such as:

```
level1
level2
    level2_subcommand_1
    level2_subcommand_2
level3
    level3_subcommand_1
```

Example:
If I typed:

```
cmd> level2
```

, I want to see level2_subcommand_1 and level2_subcommand_2 appearing when I hit the tab key, but no level1 and no level3.

I was unable to do so with the cmd lib as well as with readline.

Answer (score 13):

It works perfectly fine for me with the `cmd` module in Python 2.6.5. Here is the sample code I was using to test this:

```
import cmd

class MyInterpreter(cmd.Cmd):
    def do_level1(self, args):
        pass

    def do_level2_subcommand_1(self, args):
        pass

    def do_level2_subcommand_2(self, args):
        pass

    def do_level3_subcommand_1(self, args):
        pass

MyInterpreter().cmdloop()
```

When I type "level2" on the command line and then press Tab, the line gets expanded to `level2_subcommand_` as this is the common prefix to all the completion proposals. When I press Tab again without typing anything, the next line correctly shows `level2_subcommand_1` and `level2_subcommand_2`. Is this what you are looking for?

Another variant for the case of sub-commands is to create a sub-interpreter for them:

```
class SubInterpreter(cmd.Cmd):
    prompt = "(level2) "

    def do_subcommand_1(self, args):
        pass

    def do_subcommand_2(self, args):
        pass

    def do_quit(self, args):
        return True
    do_EOF = do_quit

class MyInterpreter(cmd.Cmd):
    def do_level1(self, args):
        pass

    def do_level2(self, args):
        sub_cmd = SubInterpreter()
        sub_cmd.cmdloop()

    def do_level3(self, args):
        pass
```

The above variant gives you `level1`, `level2` and `level3` in your "main" interpreter. When you invoke `level2` in your main interpreter, it constructs the sub-interpreter and calls its command loops. The sub-interpreter has a different prompt from the main interpreter, so you can always tell which interpreter you are in. The sub-interpreter then gives you `subcommand_1`, `subcommand_2`, `subcommand_3` and `quit`. `quit` takes you back to the main interpreter, and so does the EOF character.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The second example looks like it could do what I want. I have modified it (it calls SubInterpreter instead of SubInterpreterForLevel2) but it doesn't work. It's like I'm stuck at the first level (MyInterpreter).

Comment: Okay, I tested my second example in an actual Python interpreter. Looks like `SubInterpreterForLevel2` should be called `SubInterpreter` (as you correctly noted), plus the `do_quit` function was missing the `args` argument, but otherwise it works perfectly fine for me. Typing `level2` changes the prompt to `(level2)` and takes me to the sub-interpreter. Typing `quit` in `(level2)` takes me back to `(Cmd)`. Are you getting any error message when you type `level2`?

Answer (score 0):

argpext module from pypi implements multilevel subcommands for command line interface.
there is no support for tab completion (yet?).